# WordPress Understrap Template Install, dependencies install

Tags: node.js, wordpress, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to install Understrap Theme as a base theme for my WordPress site,

I am stuck at the point of the [dependencies install](https://understrap.github.io/#developing)

I run my development environment on a server with a running WP site already. (not locally).

What am I missing here?

sorry for the noob question, I have no experience with Terminal, npm or gulp.

How can I proceed there?

thanks in advance,
Dan.

Answer (score 0):

UnderStrap is not for the lighthearted.  It requires some work in setting up, but in my opinion, its worth it and anyone can do it if they take time to learn the tools that are needed.

The first thing you can do is make sure you upload and activate the UnderStrap theme on your live WordPress site.

Next, I highly recommend setting up a PHP/MySQL development environment locally. This is where you also install npm and gulp within your localhost environment.  Why?  So that you can take advantage of compiling SASS to CSS, minifying and bundling your `custom-javascript.js` file into the main theme.min.css, and testing for overall perfection with UnderStrap.

Once you approve of youe site locally, you could then copy your **modified** UnderStrap theme files up to your live hosting environment.

What I typically do is add a specific comment to each code file I modify within my UnderStrap theme.  When its time for me to send my local work to my live hosting environment, I would simply search for all code files that carry my specific comment. I would then upload them one at a time to their proper locations on my hosting environment.  This is one of many tactics you can apply to your work environment.

The muscle of UnderStrap is compiling SASS code, which is why you want to start all of this locally.